# BAZEL: How to exclude certain targets if a configuration setting is true

Tags: bazel

Let's say I have 3 libraries in different folders:

```
a_library(
  name = "a",
)
```

```
b_library(
  name = "b",
)
```

```
c_library(
  name = "c",
)
```

I want to `bazel build ...` to build all libraries, while `bazel build ... -c dbg` only builds `a_library` and `b_library`. I'm wondering what I should change?

What i've tried:

I tried following https://bazel.build/docs/configurable-attributes, where I made a config setting for `dbg` and selected `tag=['default']` when you passed in `-c dbg`, but apparently tags aren't configurable.

I've also tried modifying my `.bazelrc` file to add a tag to `c_library`. Eg: `build --build_tag_filters="disable_for_dbg"`, but I'm not sure how to get this to only run when I pass `-c dbg`

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[Incompatible target skipping](https://bazel.build/docs/platforms#skipping-incompatible-targets) is the feature for this. It'll exclude the libraries from wildcards, and anything which (transitively) depends on them. If you explicitly list one of them on the command line (`bazel build -c dbg c`), you'll get an error. Like this:

```py
config_setting(
    name = "debug_build",
    values = {
        "compilation_mode": "dbg",
    },
)

c_library(
    name = "c",
    target_compatible_with = select({
        ":debug_build": ["@platforms//:incompatible"],
        "//conditions:default": [],
    }),
)
```

`@platforms//:incompatible` is not part of any platform, so any target with `target_compatible_with` that includes it will always be skipped. `target_compatible_with` is configurable, so you can add that platform constraint conditionally via `select.`